# Running rsync across servers from two separate cores slows down average transfer speed?

Tags: linux, rsync

I am running an rsync command to transfer a directory from one server to another. I wish to run a second rsync command to transfer another directory. Will the transfer speed of the first one decrease? If so, will it be a drastic reduction?

Comment: It may depend even from the bottleneck of the local data access (HDD or SDD). Remember the options for sparse files (when you have a lot) and the compression (it you can earn form it and the bottleneck is the bandwidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends completely on factors like your total bandwidth, your computer specifications and server load in general.

Example: If you have a 100 mbit line and are transferring in 12 MB/s you can count on that if you start a second transfer it will be using part of the total bandwidth and reducing the first transfers speed. And eventually they would use half each. 6 MB/s for each transfer until one completes and the other uses the full bandwidth again.

That said, my experience is to not recommend that you start too many transfers at the same time on a typical server with a typical connection. If your server is very powerful and you are on a really fast connection you can start a few without problems.